# multiple add based on one date month value for multiple tables

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to add 3 filters to my second piece of code from the code below
so I get the count of by year month filtered by status id <> and region and type. I am new to SQL and just cant find a way to merge both codes to get it to work. I have spent 5 hours trying to find a solution. Any help would be much appreciated
I need a count of date created from jd.OrganisationAddress , but to filter it , I need to link the field OrganisationID from jd.OrganisationAddress to jd.Organisation table field ID , that table has field StatusID , which I need to be <>4 . Then for the type field I have to match to jd.OrganisationOrganisationType.OrganisationID from the jd.OrganisationOrganisationType table I need to link that via jd.OrganisationOrganisationType.OrganisationTypeID = jd.OrganisationType.ID , then from the jd.OrganisationType table I then need jd.OrganisationType.Name)='Bank')); then finally for the region I have to link it to the address table via jd.OrganisationAddress.AddressID = jd.Address.ID then from the address table I need to match the region by linking jdAddress.countryID to JD.country_region.countryID then jd country.region.regionID to the jd_region table field ID and then if jd_Region.name = "North America"

```
SELECT
    jd.Organisation.StatusID
  , jd.Region.Name AS Region
  , jd.OrganisationType.Name AS Type
FROM
   jd.Region
  , ((((jd.Organisation 
INNER JOIN
   jd.OrganisationAddress 
ON
   jd.Organisation.ID = jd.OrganisationAddress.OrganisationID) 
INNER JOIN
   jd.Address 
ON
   jd.OrganisationAddress.AddressID = jd.Address.ID) 
INNER JOIN
   jd.Country 
ON
   jd.Address.CountryID = jd.Country.ID) 
INNER JOIN
   jd.OrganisationOrganisationType 
ON
   jd.Organisation.ID = jd.OrganisationOrganisationType.OrganisationID) 
INNER JOIN
   jd.OrganisationType 
ON
   jd.OrganisationOrganisationType.OrganisationTypeID = jd.OrganisationType.ID
WHERE
   (((jd.Organisation.StatusID)<>4) 
AND
   ((jd.Region.Name)='North America') 
AND
   ((jd.OrganisationType.Name)='Bank'));


select year(datecreated), 
   sum(case when month(datecreated) = 1 then 1 else 0 end) Jan,
   sum(case when month(datecreated) = 2 then 1 else 0 end) Feb,
   sum(case when month(datecreated) = 3 then 1 else 0 end) Mar,
   sum(case when month(datecreated) = 4 then 1 else 0 end) Apr,
   sum(case when month(datecreated) = 5 then 1 else 0 end) May,
   sum(case when month(datecreated) = 6 then 1 else 0 end) Jun,
   sum(case when month(datecreated) = 7 then 1 else 0 end) Jul,
   sum(case when month(datecreated) = 8 then 1 else 0 end) Aug,
   sum(case when month(datecreated) = 9 then 1 else 0 end) Sep,
   sum(case when month(datecreated) = 10 then 1 else 0 end) Oct,
   sum(case when month(datecreated) = 11 then 1 else 0 end) Nov,
   sum(case when month(datecreated) = 12 then 1 else 0 end) Dec
   from jd.OrganisationAddress
   group by year(datecreated)
   order
```

by year(datecreated) ASC

Comment: Sorry, can't really understand your issue here. Please refer to `How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example` https://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex

Comment: thanks I have edited the question to explain more

Answer (score 0):

Your example looks still a bit strange to me, but I think you like to achive something like this:

(Based on the AdventureWorks2014 database)

```
SELECT 
  DATEPART(YEAR, ModifiedDate) AS [Year], 
  DATEPART(MONTH, ModifiedDate) AS [Month], 
  SUM(LineTotal) AS TurnOver 
FROM [Sales].[SalesOrderDetail]
GROUP BY DATEPART(YEAR, ModifiedDate), DATEPART(MONTH, ModifiedDate)
```

Comment: Or is it just a count you like to do?

Comment: I need a count of date created from jd.OrganisationAddress , but to filter it

Answer (score 0):

I tried some more to understand what you might want to achieve and have another answer for you (it is a bit looking into the crystal ball, sorry):

```
WITH PreSelection AS (
  SELECT 
    oa.datecreated
  FROM OrganisationAddress oa
  INNER JOIN Organisation o ON o.ID = oa.OrganisationID
  INNER JOIN [Address] a ON oa.AddressID = a.ID
  INNER JOIN Country c ON a.CountryID = c.ID
  INNER JOIN [Region] r ON a.RegionID = r.ID
  -- INNER JOIN [Region] r ON c.RegionID = r.ID
  INNER JOIN OrganisationType ot ON o.OrganisationTypeID = ot.ID
  WHERE o.StatusID <> 4
    AND r.Name = 'North America'
    AND ot.Name ='Bank'
)
SELECT 
  DATEPART(YEAR, datecreated) AS [Year], 
  DATEPART(MONTH, datecreated) AS [Month], 
  COUNT(*) AS RecordCount 
FROM PreSelection 
GROUP BY 
  DATEPART(YEAR, datecreated), 
  DATEPART(MONTH, datecreated);
```